# mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(mSocket)) - nothing written to mSocket

Tags: java, android, video

I have Service which records video from back camera:

```
this.mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
this.mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
this.mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(VideoSource.CAMERA);
this.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
this.mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
this.mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(photo_resolution[0], photo_resolution[1]);
this.mParcelFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(this.mSocket);
this.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.mParcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
this.mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());
this.mMediaRecorder.prepare();
this.mMediaRecorder.start();
```

Video doesn't have a sound. I connecting to the server with following code:

```
this.mSocket = new Socket();
this.mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(...), 30000);
this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.mSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
this.out = this.mSocket.getOutputStream();
this.out.write(("some string" + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8"));
this.out.flush();
...
```

Every needed permissions I have already added to AndroidManifest.xml.

The problem is that video isn't broadcasted to server. I tried to replace `this.mParcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()` to `"/sdcard/video.mp4"`, everything was alright - video recorded correclty. But it doesn't sends to socket. Nothing happened clientside (in my app), but serverside thrown me exception `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: read timed out`. I tried this code serverside:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int read = mSocket_inputStream.read(bytes, 0, 1024);
System.out.println(read);
```

which debug me count of read bytes from client (from my app) - nothing was debugged in console, because 0 bytes was sent. Help me solve this problem please. I didn't found solution in google.

Answer (score 1):

File descriptor only works for local server socket in MediaRecorder.

```
 this.mParcelFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(this.mSocket);
 this.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.mParcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
```

You can create your own LocalServerSocket and then pass data to actual server socket from your local server socket

To know more about local server socket you can go through https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalServerSocket.html

The more efficient way will be to use MediaCodec API for recording as it will provide you data frame by frame in format of byte buffer and you can send that data on to server.

Comment: Sorry, can you help me with this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376658/android-mediarecorder-to-socket-streaming-video-damaged. There are damaged video.